# Off-topic because... There are strange radio buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was going through the review queue and came across a question that I thought may be off-topic.
I was deciding which topic it would be off-topic for, if any. And noticed that the radio buttons are too high.
This was strange as the "why should this question be closed?" was fine.
(Horrible red underlining by me).

[image]
[image]

Just to make sure it wasn't my [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYlns.png)([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94XCD.png)) messing up, I tried in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb7vs.png) and [Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chDEm.png).
Both of which I've rarely, if ever, touched.

Comment: I confirmed same issue with Safari. Must be a CSS issue.

Comment: Confirmed under the latest Firefox Win10 ([picture](http://i.imgur.com/CRPTXFk.png).

Comment: Repro on Chrome with Windows 7.